# Where can I find the API difference between java5 and java6

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android project and support `minSdkVersion=7`. When sdk version below 8, it will use java5. And I found `String.isEmpty()` doesn't exit in java5. So it caused many crashes.

To fix crashes , I have changed `String.isEmpty()` to `String.length() == 0`. After that I searched google and didn't find a convenient document figured out the API difference between java5 and java6.

So my question is where can I find such document?

Comment: Any special reason you cannot use java 7?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy Android API 7 is my app's min support SDK version , and API 8  is Android 2.2 , it will use java 5, it is totally out of my control.

Comment: Does using API version 7 really forces the project to use JDK5? I have not seen or heard of this behavior...I have developed an application in API 7 before but I could still use JDK 6

Comment: @LawrenceChoy Not the version I use , but the user's Java version . I mean Android 2.2 use java5, not IDE's java version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no document that exhaustively lists all of the differences between different Java versions at the API level.  However, in the (Oracle Java) javadocs, new classes and classes typically have a "Since" tag that says when they were added.

For example, the javadocs for `String.isEmpty()` say:

```
public boolean isEmpty()

Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.

Returns:
    true if length() is 0, otherwise false
Since:
    1.6
```

Comment: I know this, but I cannot check every single API to see whether it support java5  or not.

Comment: You can't check every line of your code against a document either!  The real solution is to get your IDE to do it.  Compile against the minimum Android "API level" that you want your app to support.  Either way, the document that you desire does not exist ... AFAIK.

Comment: Oh thanks, you mention me to write a small tool to find all APIs have `since 1.6`.

Comment: Frankly, I'd just let the IDE do the job.

Comment: I have committed the comment before you edit above, I got this ,many thanks!